# Why can't we cancel our own upvote/downvote on Q/A?

Tags: discussion

It happened to me a few times that I upvoted a question or answer, and then thought it was actually not really worth it. However if I want to cancel my upvote, the post will get a downvote.

For example, this morning I upvoted an answer that I didn't actually use. I should have only upvoted the answer I tried, instead of the answer of someone else which looked good, but maybe didn't answer my issue.

Comment: "I should have only upvoted the answer I tried instead of the answer of someone else which looked good but maybe didn't answer my issue." not at all, the only restriction is about the accepted answer. You should only accepted an answer that solve *your* issue but it's very good to upvote other answer that are correct.

Comment: Yes, in case it is correct. I didn't check if it was in this case because a bit too long

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> if I want to cancel my upvote, the post will get a downvote

Then you hit the wrong button. If you upvoted, click the upvote button to undo. Don't use the downvote button to undo your upvote, since it does exactly what you say it does.

Note that votes are locked after 5 minutes until the post has been edited.